# getview() method does not works properly

Tags: android, android-listview, position

In my project I populate listview from sqlite database.When I click the list row it will shown in detailed view of the selected row.When I click on the list row It passes the message id from sqlite database to detailed view where the detailed content of that row will fetch from sqlite database.But It shows wrong details of the selected row.This is my code,Can anyone help me!

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View row = convertView;  
            UserHolder holder = null;
            System.out.println("positionnnn:"+position);
            if (row == null) {

            //   LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                  //  v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message, null);
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            System.out.println("positionnnn:"+position);



            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inboxcustom,parent,false);

            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.fromnum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.fromno);
            holder.tonum = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tonum);
            holder.body= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msgbody);
            holder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.msgdate);
            holder.readunread=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            user = data.get(position);
            System.out.println("user:::::" + user);
            smsm=user.getID();
            System.out.println("Smsm::::"+smsm);
            System.out.println("Array list size in getview method inbox:::"+data.size());
            holder.fromnum.setText(user.getmsgfrom());
            holder.tonum.setText(user.getto());
            holder.body.setText(user.getmsg());
            holder.date.setText(user.getdate());
           // holder.status.setText(user.getstatus());
        //    holder.readunread.set
         System.out.println("status value:::"+user.getstatus());
         String zero="0";
         System.out.println("Zero value:::"+zero);
            if(user.getstatus().equals(zero)){
                 int  dailyun=dbHandler.calculateunread();
                 System.out.println("unreadcount in inbox activity::"+dailyun);

        holder.readunread.setImageResource(R.drawable.messageunread);
            } 

           row.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));

            return row;

        }
```

Please anyone help me!Thanks in Advance!!!